# Expand gtkmm GtkTreeView column

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtktreeview

Im looking forward to expand one of my gtkmm treeview columns so it would use all the space left, and shrink other columns... Its there any way to do this?

```
m_ScrolledWindow.add(m_TreeView);
m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC, Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC);


m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_Columns);
m_TreeView.set_model(m_refTreeModel);

m_TreeView.append_column("ID", m_Columns.m_col_id);
m_TreeView.append_column("Task", m_Columns.m_col_task);
/// I WANT TO EXPAND TASK COLUMN
m_TreeView.append_column("Time", m_Columns.m_col_time);
m_TreeView.append_column("Date", m_Columns.m_col_date);
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the other columns completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#a7e948adaeeafd9884ba5ca7d639f9ea7)

EDIT: I was wrong, see correct way below (works in my code)

You would need to do this:

```
m_TreeView.get_column(1)->set_expand(true);
```

(replace '1' with actual position counting from 0 and left to right)

Note: This just makes column 'n' take up all free space. It won't hide any other columns.

Comment: Im getting errors when building...

/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/treeviewcolumn.h:121:19: error: ‘Gtk::TreeViewColumn& Gtk::TreeViewColumn::operator=(const Gtk::TreeViewColumn&)’ is private
/home/juanchi/MeTaskManager/src/gui.cpp:38:34: error: within this context

Comment: Try `m_TreeView.set_expander_column(*(m_TreeView.get_column(n));`
(Where 'n' is the column number from 0)